# Visual Studio 2010 keyboard shortcut for next reference in C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 (C++) when I use Shift-F12 to invoke Edit.FindAllReferences(), I expect the F8 key to jump my cursor to the next found reference. It did on my old machine, but I just got a new one and now it does not.

Is there a different keyboard shortcut, or better yet, what is the command to jump the cursor to the next Find Symbol Results item?

(Yes, I tried Google... best I could find is F8 for when you invoke a Find  All, and in the case of Find All, it does work, but I want "Find All References". I wouldn't have expected a difference...)

Thanks,
  Karl

Answer (score 2):

The F8 works on mine. Did you check your keyboard mappings. The default keyboard may have been setup differently (at install, there are choices like VC++2, VC++6, etc...)

Open Tools/Options Menu

Choose environment/keyboard on the left

On the Options dialog, find the "Press shortcut keys:" text box. Put your cursor in that box and press the F8 key.

Just below it in the Shortcut currently used by: "Edit.GoToNextLocation(F8 (Global)).

If it doesn't say that, you may want to change your default keyboard mapping scheme.

Comment: The only mapping F8 has is Edit.GoToNextLocation (F8 (Global)). Why does it work in one context and not another?  Thanks, Karl

Comment: And, that setup works on mine. I wonder if you possibly have a blown install. You might try adding an additional keyboard mapping scheme (on the environment/keyboard selection of the options dialog as described above). The Visual Studio 6 has the same key mapping for F8. Also might just try pressing the Reset button on that page, see if it helps.

Comment: Wow. Weird. As suggested, I removed the mapping to F8, and added it again. Now, after a Shift-F12, when I hit F8, it will go to the definition of that variable. Additional F8 presses do nothing UNLESS I use the mouse to double click another found reference in the Find Symbol Results window. Once I have done that, F8 cycles through them as expected. The next time I use Shift-F12, I'm right back to the definition and nothing else. This is weird. Some other context's mapping has to be clobbering it, but I can't seem to find it.